# Python live streaming input to csv or json

Tags: python, json, csv, streaming

I need to make a python script that gives me csv or json file with random numbers (or print every number from 0 to 100000000 for example) so I can use it for testing live stream processing tool. An idea is to send me SMS when hit some number in that tool. But I have no idea how to make csv or json that's gone be used for live streaming...

To be easier...
What is python code to make an input to csv from 0 to 100000 in one column named 'Numbers'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates file.csv, with one column with all numbers from 0 to 99.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Numbers'])
    csv_writer.writerows([[x] for x in range(100)])
```